# On Server URLs are case sensitive for CakePHP standard URLs?

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

So I have a CakePHP install and the UsersAdmin controller shows fine in `/usersadmin/index` on local - but on an actual server it is case sensitive (will only show if I have `usersAdmin/index`) - any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: use cakephp routing like Router::connect(
    '/usersadmin/index',
    array('controller' => 'usersAdmin', 'action' => 'index')
);

Answer (score 0):

First You have to add this to your httpd.conf:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then paste the below code into your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
```

This code redirct the url like from

```
www.tESTUrl.com/usersAdmin/index/?q=SomeStringHere
```

to

```
www.testurl.com//usersadmin/index/?q=SomeStringHere
```